# SQL-инъекция в $port

Tags: php, mysql

Залил php скрипт на find-xss.net, мне показало, что там SQL-инъекция в параметре $port, вот:

```
$port=$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];

mysql_query("insert into logs(logindate,username,ipaddr,timestamp,port) values('$date','$loguser','$ip','$timestamp','$port')");
```

Как провести SQL-инъекцию? Пробовал по-разному, не подходило.

Comment: Если только на стороне клиента подделать $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'] это теоретически возможно, но трудоемко. В любом случае лучше таки воспользоваться функцией mysql_real_escape_string() - $port = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']). Возьмите за правило - не доверять никаким данным, приходящим со стороны клиента.

Comment: Эээ, `REMOTE_PORT` формируется не клиентом, а веб-сервером и всегда является числом. Не осознаю суть инъекции.

Comment: А вы уверены что именно $port виноват? А остальные переменные как-то обрабатываются?

Answer (score 1):

Весь массив $_SERVER приходит от пользователя, удаленный сервер тот же пользователь. Как именно использовать уязвимость я не скажу, но думаю способ есть. Раз $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'] формируется сервером.